# Building Maui MS Tutorial App: Get error APT2260: resource mipmap/appicon and mipmap/appicon_round not found

Tags: build, maui, build-error, multiplatform

Most of the posts I found related to this issue were created when Maui was still in beta.
**This issue affected the Android build only**! The iOS build worked the first time.

Following [this Microsoft Maui tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LH4z74QBWU8), I experienced a build issue right out the gate. The error was `APT2260: resource mipmap/appicon and mipmap/appicon_round not found`.

In the resources folder there was no `appicon_round.svg` file, so I copied `appicon.svg` to `appicon_round.svg` and tried a rebuild and got the same error.

I deleted `android:roundIcon="@mipmap/appicon_round"` from `AndroidManifest.xml`, and deleted the `appicon_round.svg` file I created via a `copy` action, but the build still failed.

Even though `appicon.svg` did exist, I removed `android:icon="@mipmap/appicon"` from `AndroidManifest.xml`, and the rebuild was successful. ‍♂️

Finally, I used Inkscape to create `appicon_round.svg`, I added it to the projects `Resources/AppIcon` folder, and then added `android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/appicon_round"` back to the `AndroidManifest.xml` file. The following build was successful.

First thing to note is that, while Visual Studio 2022 for MacOS did create the `appicon.svg` file, it did not generate the `appicon_round.svg` when I created the Multi-Platform project.

The second "gotcha" for me was when I removed the round SVG reference from the Android manifest file, but the build still failed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To summarize how to resolved the issue, if you generate a multi-platform project in Visual Studio 2022 for MacOS and any `AppIcon` SVG files are missing ...

1. Remove both/all AppIcon references from the `AndroidManifest.xml`
2. Build the app.
3. Generate the missing `AppIcon` SVG file(s) and put them in the correct folder.
4. Add both/all AppIcon references back to the `AndroidManifest.xml`
5. Build the app.

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT, thanks and will do. But I have to wait 48 hours before I am able to accept my own answer.

Comment: I'm on 17.6.6 and this doesn't work for me

Answer (score 20):

Sometimes I face the same build error while trying to deploy `MAUI` app to `Android` device in `Release mode` via `Visual Studio for Mac`.

The solution that works in my case is also simple:

1. Manually delete project's `bin` and `obj` folders.
2. Restart `Visual Studio for Mac`.
3. Open app's project.
4. `Build` -> `Build solution`.

Comment: This works for Windows as well. Thanks.

Comment: Followed same steps, Worked.

Comment: Just restarting IDE fixes this silly error inside JetBrains Rider too.

Comment: 2024, still same issue. No code changes, just release from default project. Unbelievable.

Answer (score 14):

I changed

```
<MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appiconx.png" />
```

to a not existing file, build, get another error message, changed it back to the original filename and build again.
No errors any more.
No choke!
(VS 17.8.3, dotnet 8.0.100, target runtime net8.0)

Comment: Great workaround :)

Comment: This answer, nor any of the other solutions here worked for me and I'm using Visual Studio 2022 for Windows.  I'm using an SVG for background and another SVG for the foreground.  Both are SVG version 1.1.  Nothing works.  I'm completely stuck :(

Comment: Despite does not make any sense, it works for me as well.

Answer (score 2):

After updating net7-android to net8-android I started getting the same error. After I updated the nuget packages Microsoft.Maui.Controls and Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility to version 8.0.6, after which the build went without errors.

Perhaps removing these packages and reinstalling them with version 8.0.3 will help too. Because on my other computer this same project builds normally with versions 8.0.3.

P.S. before this I cleaned out the bin and obj folders

Answer (score 0):

This issue is sure in new created project.

It resolve this "missing file reference"
rename example "dotnet_bot.svg" -> to appicon.svg

- and now it works and can be build without errors

[My solution it works - image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4BWG.png)

Code:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <!-- App Icon -->
    <MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" Color="#FFFFFF" ForegroundScale="0.5" />
    <!-- Images -->
    <MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\*" />
    <MauiImage Update="Resources\Images\dotnet_bot.svg" BaseSize="168,208" />
    <MauiImage Update="Resources\Images\appicon.svg" />
    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <MauiFont Include="Resources\Fonts\*" />
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all: do not touch AndroidManifest.xml, it is not needed. The problem was in my project file, I had the comment `<!-- App Icon -->` but nothing under it.

So, fill your icon information under it:

```
<MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.png" />
```

Be sure it is inside a `<ItemGroup></ItemGroup>`

Then you have to clear and build your solution and uninstall the app in the mobile device and install it again.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error when attempting to generate an Android AAB by right-clicking the project and selecting *Build*, as suggested in a video I saw. None of the above solutions worked for me.

What solved it for me was selecting *Publish* instead of *Build* - the error did not occur. Duh.

As an aside, I had been worried I would not be able to publish at all because, in a Windows VM in Parallels on an M2 Mac, I was unable to get Android emulators to work, and you have to select one before publishing. (Parallels does not support a VM within a VM.) However, it turned out to be enough to select the non-functional Android emulator I had installed. Apparently it's just to indicate the platform to publish on. What a relief.

Answer (score 0):

The way that worked for me was to:

1. Unistall the app on the target platform
2. Clean the solution.
3. Build the solution.

I saw that workaround here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/images/app-icons?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=windows

[image from url link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMtDt.png)

Hope this could help.