# .NET MAUI - ERROR "resource mipmap/appicon (aka com.company.tkpay:mipmap/appicon) not found."

Tags: c#, xamarin, maui

I've been working on a .NET MAUI project for a few weeks, and I've recently encountered an error as shown in the image below:

[ErrorSolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VI8oJ.png)

I noticed that many people have encountered this same error, but I haven't been able to find a viable solution for my specific issue. I suspect it might be related to some file generation issue within the framework itself.

When I remove the references from the AndroidManifest, the error no longer occurs, and I'm able to debug my project. However, this leads to all the images in the Android app disappearing. Is there a potential solution for my AndroidManifest file, keeping in mind that my target platform is Android?

[AndroidManifest.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wg5z2.png)

Comment: This is because VS sometimes has a glitch... Try the solutions in this case: [Get error APT2260: resource mipmap/appicon and mipmap/appicon_round not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74646526/building-maui-ms-tutorial-app-get-error-apt2260-resource-mipmap-appicon-and-mi). In addtion, create a new project and build it, see if it will work without error?

Comment: @JianweiSun-MSFT The error persists even when I create a new solution. It's difficult to understand the source of the problem because when I debug on a different computer, the issue doesn't occur. Should I consider reinstalling Visual Studio?

Comment: *Should I consider reinstalling Visual Studio?* Yes, you can also update your VS to the latest version.